# Why this if else condition is not not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

$taskid=$this->privacy();

```
       if($taskid){I returning something in one function and then by reference to this return,I am fetching data from another table in second function using if condition in such a way that if data(return) found in first table then execute else leave empty
```

But I data found in first table then every thing is fine,hower data not found in first table then it shows as Notice: Undefined variable: task in....

I think error is in if else condition.Please help or suggest any alternative approach.

Plz also note that that I am working on pricacy table

first function returning rows

```
function privacy()
{
   $session=new session();

   $sql2=mysqli_query($this->db->connection,"SELECT * from privacy where viewerid='$session->userid'");
   while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($sql2)){
     $task[]=$row2['task'];
   }
   return $task;
 }
```

function 2.. if found something then do something else  do nothing(but error appears as undefined variable)

```
 function showactivityo4apply()
 {
    $session=new session();
    $taskid=$this->privacy();
    if($taskid){
       foreach($taskid as $fvid){
         $sql=mysqli_query($this->db->connection,"SELECT * FROM activity where id='$fvid'");
         while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
            $name_id=$row['sub_id'];  
            echo  $name;                   
          }
        }
     }      
     else{}
   }
```

Comment: Instead of typing your code (and changing it) you really should copy and paste it straight from your file

Answer (score 0):

`if($taskid=$this->privacy())` is assigning a value of `$this->privacy()` to `$taskid`

I think you mean

`if($taskid == $this->privacy())`

Comment: way to change your question

Answer (score 0):

If condition have == sign not = sign

```
if($taskid==$this->privacy()){
}
 else
{
}
```

= means assign value to another

== check the value to other variable

Answer (score 0):

it is showing notice because php is not getting value in array on key "task" use isset() function to check whether data is available or not
use like this

```
$task[] = (isset($row2['task'])?$row2['task']:'';
```

if value is not set in $row2['task'] then it will assign blank value in $task[] array.

and one more change you have to do

instead of if($taskid)  condition use

```
if( count($taskid) > 0){
}
```

so that if record not found in array it will not inter in to the loop

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: task in

Comment: Please change also like : $sql=mysqli_query($this->db->connection,"SELECT * FROM activity where id='. " . $fvid . "'");

Comment: I dont think so double quote style makes any difference in functionality?

Comment: please provide the exact and full Notice you are getting. with the line it is giving error on

Answer (score 0):

```
please change this line of your code like: 

  $sql2=mysqli_query($this->db->connection,"SELECT * from privacy where 
viewerid='$session->userid'");
=========================================
to
=============================
  $sql2=mysqli_query($this->db->connection,"SELECT * from privacy where 
viewerid='" . $session->userid . "'");

 =======================
```

conclution: Here $session->userid  is not found thats why you not get result.